# the scope of variable in vim

Tags: vimscript, variables

I believe the following script in vimrc, which try to set `spellfile`, has something to do with the scope of vim variable. Especially the difference of `$var` and `g:var`:

I can't figure out what's wrong with this:

```
let g:spelldir ='~/.vim/myvim/spell'
if !exists( 'g:spelldir' )
  silent exec '!mkdir -p ' . g:spelldir
endif
au FileType tex setlocal spf= g:spelldir/en.utf-8.add
```

while it works if we change `g:spelldir` to `$spelldir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `isdirectory` not `exists` to check if a directory exists.
2. `set`/`setlocal` does not expand variables but it does (sometimes) expand environment variables, which explains what you're seeing.  Use this instead:

   ```
   au FileType tex exe 'setlocal spf='.g:spelldir.'/en.utf-8'
   ```

The `g:spelldir` is copied into the `setlocal` string when the `FileType` autocommand is triggered, then the whole string is executed.  It has nothing to do with variable scope, `g:` is global.